# Bing Custom Search - thumbnail near each search result

Tags: bing, azure-cognitive-services, google-custom-search

Last couple years for the search function on our website, we used Google Custom Search.
Since the service will be disabled - we recently switched from GCS to Bing Custom Search (https://customsearch.ai/)

Currently, we can't retrieve thumbnail images for the each row in search results. Is it possible with Bing Custom Search? I mean - we want to display page thumbnail from the Bing near each search result.

Answer (score 0):

Custom search provides **contentUrl** for each result in json that is not a page preview but image that you can associate with the result. You could use that as a thumbnail, if that helps.